# Using decorator inside a function

Tags: python, python-decorators

Inside a function I'm using a retry mechanism like that (always in a try/except block):

```
        def load(self):
            [........]
            # Retry mechanism for locking database 
            for i in range(1, max_connection_retries+1):                        
                try:
                    cu.lock()
                    break
                except LockError as l_error:
                    if i < max_connection_retries:
                        sleep(20)
                        continue
                    else:
                        raise ContinuableError (logger.console(datetime.now().time().strftime ("%b %d %H:%M:%S") + ' ERROR:Impossible to lock the database after %i retries' % max_connection_retries))
        [.......]
```

I'm using this mechanism several times in others part of the same function and in other functions. It would be possible to apply a decorator to only this part of the code ? something like that:

```
        def load(self): 
            [.......]
            @retry(max=5,message='blablabla')                       
            try:
                cu.lock()
                break
            except LockError as l_error:

            [.......]

            @retry(max=5)                       
            try:
                cu.unlock()
                break
            except LockError as l_error:
```

If so, could you help me showing me an example of a decorator for doing such task ?

Comment: Decorators only work on functions. Also why wouldn't you just use a method here and pass the retry parameters as arguments? It looks like you're trying to run the same code each time.

Comment: @KurtStutsman - I'm not sure about the OP's specific use-case, but I know I've seen old code where the `retry` portion was done on a number of functions, and the retry was agnostic as to the underlying functionality (`lock`, `unlock`, `update`, `delete`, etc - database commands or something). This seems like a perfect use-case for using the `decorator` functionality rather than cluttering 10 methods with `maxRetries`. That said, your first sentence is spot on, and what the OP needs to move forward.

Answer (score 5):

The decorator syntax is just syntactic sugar for

```
# f could be a class as well
def f():
    ...
f = retry(f)
```

It cannot be applied to arbitrary anonymous blocks of code. The main purpose of a decorator is to rebind a name, and an anonymous block, by definition, has no name.

What you would need to do is refactor the code you want to retry into a function that gets decorated. For example,

```
@retry(max=5, message='blablabla')
def get_lock():
    try:
        cu.lock()
    except LockError as l_error:
        # Some action dependent on the implementation of retry


def load(self):
    get_lock()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer , I will try this approach

Answer (score 2):

As said decorator can be applied only to function, but can move "retry" logic to separate function and pass `cu.lock`/`cu.unlock` (and other stuff like `max`, `messge`) to that function as params:

```
def retry(func, tries, message):
    for i in range(1, tries+1):                        
        try:
            func()  # <- call passed function
            break
        except LockError as l_error:
            if i < tries:
                sleep(20)
                continue
            else:
                raise ContinuableError('...')

def load(self):
    retry(cu.lock, tries=5, message='blablabla')  # pass cu.lock to be called

    retry(cu.unlock, tries=5, message='blablabla')  # pass cu.unlock to be called
```